# Unregister namespaces in scope of context node

Tags: xml, perl, xpath, libxml2, xml-libxml

I am using XML::LibXML. In creating an XPath context, I need to be able to specify exactly which namespaces are available. However, all of the namespaces in the scope of the context node are automatically registered with the XPathContext object. I need to unregister those, but I get an error when I try to unregister a namespace which is in the scope of the context node:

```
use XML::LibXML;
use XML::LibXML::XPathContext;

my $xml = <<'__EOI__';
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<myDoc id="myDocId">
    <body id="bodyId">
    <baz:par xmlns:baz="www.baz.com"
             xmlns:bar="www.bar.com">
        <bar:id>xyz123</bar:id>
    </baz:par>
    </body>
</myDoc>
__EOI__

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc = $parser->parse_string($xml);

my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new();
$xpc->registerNs('baz', 'www.baz.com');

my $par = ${ $xpc->findnodes('//baz:par', $doc) }[0];

my $xpc2 = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($par);
$xpc2->unregisterNs('bar');
```

The above croaks `XPathContext: cannot unregister namespace`. Inspecting the source, I see that the error is printed from line 7618 of [LibXML.xs](https://metacpan.org/source/SHLOMIF/XML-LibXML-2.0019/LibXML.xs). It is printed when the function `xmlXPathRegisterNs` returns -1. The only documentation for this function I can find is on [xmlsoft.org](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xpathInternals.html#xmlXPathRegisterNs). This documentation specifies that a -1 return value means that there was an error, but doesn't specify under what conditions an error occurs. I cannot for the life of me find the source for that method.

It may very well be that the [XPath specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) disallows this particular operation, but I am unable to determine that, either.

Can anyone tell me a) if there is a way to unregister namespaces in the scope of the context node using XML::LibXML::XPathContext or b) where there is documentation that this is not allowed in XPath?

**EDIT**

Joel showed me that unregistering a namespace only throws the given error if you haven't manually registered the namespace. However, unregistering still doesn't work right:

```
$xpc2->registerNs('bar', 'nothing'); #otherwise unregistering throws an error
$xpc2->unregisterNs('bar');
my @nodes = $xpc2->find('bar:id');
print scalar @nodes; #I want '0', but this prints '1'
```

Comment: Can you show how the XML should look like after the transformations? Do you want the `<bar:id>` element be written instead as `<id xmlns="www.bar.com">`, without the namespace prefix?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer about what the program does, which is actually nothing. There is no transformation here. I just want to unregister 'bar' without an error being thrown.

Comment: But why do you want to do the unregister if there's no serialization or anything else afterwards?

Comment: Because the W3C spec I'm implementing requires that I do an XPath query in which a certain node is the context node, but a completely different node is used to provide the set of namespaces available to the XPath query.

Comment: Or at least that was the interpretation I had. I'm beginning to think that registering namespaces for the context is different from a namespace just being in scope, and that it is not possible to remove namespaces from scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation of the Perl bindings. `XML::LibXML` always [registers all namespaces in scope of the context node](https://metacpan.org/source/SHLOMIF/XML-LibXML-2.0106/LibXML.xs#L1393). All you can do is to rebind an existing prefix to another namespace like you did in the edit section of your question. If you remove the call to `unregisterNS`, it should do what you want:

```
$xpc2->registerNs('bar', 'nothing'); # Rebind prefix
my @nodes = $xpc2->findnodes('bar:id', $par);
print scalar(@nodes), "\n"; # Prints 0
```

Comment: Ah, this makes sense. "nothing" is (hopefully) never used as a namespace URI. I could be more obvious and say "NULL_NS_URI" or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Is it because the `bar` namespace has not been registered yet?  If I add `$xpc2->registerNs('bar', 'www.bar.com');` just before the `unregisterNs` call, the program runs fine for me.  Does this produce the behavior you want?

**Update from the additional information:**
The way you're doing your query may be revealing a bug in libxml or XML::LibXML; I'm not familiar enough with XPathContext to know if it is a bug or not.  So I tried something that confuses me, I did a `lookupNS` after I did the `unregisterNS` and I still got the correct NS:

```
$xpc2->registerNs('bar', 'www.bar.com');
$xpc2->unregisterNs('bar');
print $xpc2->lookupNs('bar') . "\n"; # print www.bar.com
```

However, I may have a solution that does what you're looking for.  Instead of using `'bar'` as the prefix I tried using `'bob'` instead and I think it may give you the behavior you're looking for:

```
$xpc2->registerNs('bob', 'www.bar.com');
$xpc2->unregisterNs('bob');
my @nodes = $xpc2->find('bob:id');
print scalar @nodes . "\n";
```

Doing it this way causes the `find` method to throw an exception.  The code will not get to the `print scalar` command.

Comment: The behavior is still not right. Thanks- I edited the question to add this extra information

Comment: But doing `find('bar:id')` still returns a node. I want an error to be thrown instead of anything being returned.